# Ionic storage is returning expected array as a string

Tags: typescript, ionic4, ionic-storage, cordova-sqlite-storage

I'm storing ID's in the storage.

See example:
[image]

I store the storage to a local string [];

The problem is when I try to push new ids to storage.

```js
  addIdToDontShowList(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.storage.get(DONT_SHOW).then((ids: string[]) => {
      if (ids) {
        console.log('ids', ids);
        ids.push(id);
        return this.storage.set(DONT_SHOW, ids);
      } else {
        return this.storage.set(DONT_SHOW, id);
      }
    });
  }
```

I get an error that the method push does not exist on IDs.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: ids.push is not a function
TypeError: ids.push is not a function

How do I convert ids to a string [] so that I can push new items to ids before setting the storage again?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making my initial commit to storage and array.

Instead of return this.storage.set(DONT_SHOW, id);
I stored the id into and array and set it using the array.